# add ajaxStart and ajaxStop with $("body").on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to take away the ability to submit a form when an ajax call is in process (it is a long query and I don't want it submitted again while it is being initially made.) However I seem to be attaching it incorrectly.

```
$(function(){


    $("body").on("click", "#process", function(){

        submit_form();

    });



    $("body").on("ajaxStart", "*", function(){

        $("body").off("click", "#process", submit_form);

        alert("test");
        var div = $("<div>", {
                id: "loading",
                html: "Working"
            }).prependTo("body");

    });


    $("body").on("ajaxStop", "*", function(){
        alert("done");
        $("#loading").remove();

    });

});
```

I'm not seeing either the div being attached or the alerts being fired. I feel like there may be an issue with the `*` selector within my `on()` statements. I don't know though. I've tried to attach the ajaxStart with `on` so that `$("#loading")` which is dynamically added, can be removed.

Comment: most likely you are incorrectly binding to the ajaxstop and start events. have you been to the api? http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: Why are you using `$("body").on("ajaxStop", "*"` anyway? did you just copy it from something else? it doesn't really make any sense in this context.

Comment: @KevinB yes, I've been to the API. It doesn't show how to use `ajaxStart()` with `on()`

Comment: Maybe because... it isn't supposed to be used with .on?

Comment: @thomas and your syntax for .off() is strange

Comment: @A.Wolff, yeah, you're right.

Comment: @thomas not really what i'd expect  :)  `$("body").off("click")` or used namespaced event

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah. okay. ammended. >< not corrected. What is the right way?

Comment: @A.Wolff the API makes is seem like I pass `off` the function to be removed by calling it by name without quotes of parenthesis. `function flash() {
  $( "div" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
} $( "body" )
    .off( "click", "#theone", flash )`

Comment: set a boolean var to false when the ajax call starts and return it when the form is submitted. set it back to true when the ajax call completes. now the form will submit.

Comment: @thomas correct, I never used it like that

Comment: @A.Wolff How do you use it?

Comment: @thomas using namespace: `$("body").off( "click.namespace");`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something more along the lines of setting a variable to allow/disallow the AJAX call:

```
var processing = false;

$('form').on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    if(processing === false){

        processing = true;

        // allow AJAX here
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sample.com/process',
            type: 'POST',
            complete: function(){

                processing = false;

            }
        });
    }

});
```